# getting input value before submit

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to subtract an input field value from a database value
how to manage that??
what changes do i need in the MVC ?? 
my code in myform.ctp as follows:

```
echo $this->Form->input('discount', array('label' => 'Discount'));

$val1 = //---------here the input value ---------//
$val2 = $this->data['Product']['price'];  //value from database
$val3 = $val2 - $val1;

echo $val3;
```

---

after editing :

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('discount', array('id'=>'n','label' => 'Discount %','placeholder'=>'Value in %'));

echo $this->Form->hidden('price', array('id'=>'p'));


echo $this->Form->input('finalprice', array('id'=>'c'));

        ?>
            <script>

            var a=document.getElementById('n').value;
             document.write(a); 

            var b=document.getElementById('p').value;
             document.write(b); 

            var c=b-a;
            document.getElementById('c').value=c;
             document.write(c); 

    </script>
```

now im getting the inputs values, made the operation , but i need to insert the final value into database field... data['Product']['finalprice'] .........how to do that?

Comment: I can't get the input data value to make this operation unless i submit it

Comment: Can you make more clearly what you want to do? You want to access a input value from a user from a form before the user submits the data?

Comment: a user insert a value, i should make operation on this value, the problem is: i cant get this value from input field before submitting it

Comment: why do you need to make operation before submit? if you need some processing before you send data to server (what submit is for) then you need javascript.

Comment: & how to manage that with javascript ??

Comment: How you are getting this value----------->

$this->data['Product']['price'];

Comment: this from database -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code wrie in your `Product` Model which is inbuilt functionality of cakephp

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!empty($this->data['Product']['discount']) &&
        !empty($this->data['Product']['price'])
    ) {

     $this->data['Product']['finalprice'] = 
            $this->data['Product']['price'] - $this->data['Product']['discount'];
    }
    return true;
}
```

Check [**Manual**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) for `beforeSave` function in cakephp.

Comment: FINALLY someone understand me .... i've also tried that in this function but i think i've missed something, any way thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks alooot

Answer (score 0):

First set the value at controller

```
 $this->set('val1',$this->data['Product']['price']);
```

Then In view

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $val1; ?>" id="val1">
 <?php  echo $this->Form->input('discount', array('label' => 'Discount','id'=>'val2')); ?> 



<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var finalval=parseInt($('#val1').val())-parseInt($('#val2').val());
     alert(finalval);
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: i get : Undefined variable: val1